# how to show output from folder directoryInfo asp.net

Tags: asp.net, directoryinfo

I have this code_behind that get some info from an folder and then show the files on my page.

```
Sub fileinfo()
    Dim objDI As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("upload/files/"))
    Dim allFile As New ArrayList()
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.png"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.bmp"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.gif"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.doc"))
    allFile.AddRange(objDI.GetFiles("*.docx"))

    Me.showfiles.DataSource = allFile
    Me.showfiles.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Then i have this code on my main page, but i get an table how can i do so i only get the UL/LI list !?
Im new to this and not a pro.

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
                            <asp:DataList ID="showfiles" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="10">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li class="span2"><a class="thumbnail" href="#"><asp:ImageButton ID="folderfiles" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("upload/files/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name")) %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("Name") %>' height="82" width="119" /></a></li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
                            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay in that case just set the property `RepeatLayout="flow"` in datalist i.e.

```
<asp:DataList ID="showfiles" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="10" RepeatLayout="flow">
    <ItemTemplate>
        // existing stuff
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```